# Why do I have the same Saves from another Computer on Steam?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

Earlier I decided to play Skyrim, a game I bought off of steam.

When I clicked 'Play' on the Steam menu, it asked me a question: 'This game is overlapped', and gave me two options, though I only remember one. It said if I wanted to run it on a sort of cloud system? I'm not too sure.

Though I chose the other choice; and once the game loaded I selected "Continue". Yet it loaded another Skyrim save off my other computer!

I'm wondering how to get my old save back.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the save back.

It sounds like you saw something like the following image.

[image]

The first option is to use the files in the cloud. This means loading the files that another computer you signed into put on the cloud, and deleting what was already on this computer.

The second option is to put what was on this computer onto the cloud.

If you wanted to use what was on the computer you should have picked the second option.

Comment: That dialog doesn't indicate that the local files will be deleted, or that the choice is irrevocable. Do you have some other source or experience supporting that?